# Select rows if multiple column values are same (or null)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe
df1:

| val0 | dir0 | val1 | dir1 | val2 | dir2 | val3 | dir3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a0 | up | a1 |  | a2 | up | a3 | up |
| b0 | up | b1 | down | b2 | up | b3 | up |
| c0 |  | c1 | down | c2 | down | c3 | down |
| d0 | up | d1 |  | d2 |  | d3 | up |
| e0 | up | e1 | down | e2 | down | e3 | up |
| f0 |  | f1 | up | f2 |  | f3 |  |

I want to select rows that have only one direction (or null). So [dir0, dir1, dir2, dir3] must either contain only 'up' or only 'down' not both (empty is allowed).

df_out:

| val0 | dir0 | val1 | dir1 | val2 | dir2 | val3 | dir3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a0 | up | a1 |  | a2 | up | a3 | up |
| c0 |  | c1 | down | c2 | down | c3 | down |
| d0 | up | d1 |  | d2 |  | d3 | up |
| f0 |  | f1 | up | f2 |  | f3 |  |

Is there a good (and scalable) way of doing this or do I have to do the hard-coded comparison like:

```
df_out = df1[( ( (df1['dir0'] == 'up')   | (df1['dir0'].isnull()) ) & ......) | 
             ( ( (df1['dir0'] == 'down') | (df1['dir0'].isnull()) ) & ......)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter only `dir` columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), then test for `up`, missing values or `down` with test if all values per rows are `True`s by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df1 = df.filter(like='dir')
m1 = df1.eq('up')
m2 = df1.isna()
m3 = df1.eq('down')

df = df[(m1 | m2).all(axis=1) | (m3 | m2).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
  val0 dir0 val1  dir1 val2  dir2 val3  dir3
0   a0   up   a1   NaN   a2    up   a3    up
2   c0  NaN   c1  down   c2  down   c3  down
3   d0   up   d1   NaN   d2   NaN   d3    up
5   f0  NaN   f1    up   f2   NaN   f3  None
```

Performance for 60k rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

In [176]: %%timeit
     ...: df1 = df.filter(like='dir')
     ...: m1 = df1.fillna('up').eq('up').all(axis=1)
     ...: m2 = df1.fillna('down').eq('down').all(axis=1)
     ...: 
     ...: df[m1 | m2]
     ...: 
59.9 ms ± 531 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


In [177]: %%timeit
     ...: df1 = df.filter(like='dir')
     ...: m1 = df1.eq('up')
     ...: m2 = df1.isna()
     ...: m3 = df1.eq('down')
     ...: 
     ...: df[(m1 | m2).all(axis=1) | (m3 | m2).all(axis=1)]
     ...: 
     ...: 
44.4 ms ± 2.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


In [178]: %%timeit
     ...: df[df.filter(like='dir').apply(lambda x: len(set(i for i in x if isinstance(i, str))), axis=1).le(1)]
     ...: 
529 ms ± 25.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: why did you delete and repost your answer?

Comment: I had not seen, next time let me know, I'll UV ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to set and ensure length is ≤ 1:

```
df[df.filter(like='dir').apply(lambda x: len(set(i for i in x if isinstance(i, str))), axis=1).le(1)]
```

This is a quite fast approach compared to `nunique`. Interestingly, one rare case where `apply` seems faster.

Timing on 60k rows (`df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)`)

```
# multiple masks approach
28.4 ms ± 342 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# set approach
274 ms ± 2.37 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# nunique approach
2.86 s ± 25.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

output:

```
  val0 dir0 val1  dir1 val2  dir2 val3  dir3
0   a0   up   a1   NaN   a2    up   a3    up
2   c0  NaN   c1  down   c2  down   c3  down
3   d0   up   d1   NaN   d2   NaN   d3    up
5   f0  NaN   f1    up   f2   NaN   f3  None
```

Comment: Let me re-check, I might have done a mistake

Comment: and remove ` Interestingly, one rare case where apply seems faster.` ;)

Comment: @jezrael yes I had the wrong order, but anyway, the real surprise is between set and nunique, I don't understand it

Comment: Yes, no idea why so slow.